# How to drill-through to see details of calculated measures?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a large database containing order information. I created a detail table of order details, a very small version of it is below.

| Date | Part No. | Origin | Destination | Cost | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/29/2023 | 100 | MIA | MCO | $500 | 500 |
| 1/29/2023 | 100 | TLH | ATL | $450 | 500 |
| 1/30/2023 | 100 | JFK | MIA | $700 | 500 |
| 2/1/2023 | 100 | MCO | SFB | $700 | 500 |

I used DAX measures to create a matrix showing which locations were sending stock back to the originating plant after it has already shipped the item out.

This resulted in the following matrix:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Location with Inbound and Outbound | 2 |
| Inbound/Outbound Quantity | 1,500 |
| Inbound/Outbound % of Volume | 75% |

When selecting the '2' in the "Location with Inbound and Outbound" row, I would like to be able to see a detailed table of the movements that comprised those two movements.

Ideal Result table:

| Date | Part No. | Origin | Destination | Cost | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/29/2023 | 100 | MIA | MCO | $500 | 500 |
| 1/30/2023 | 100 | JFK | MIA | $700 | 500 |
| 2/1/2023 | 100 | MCO | SFB | $700 | 500 |

How can this be accomplished using DAX or power query?

Comment: Why would row 2 MIA ATL not be shown as well?

Comment: i had a typo and updated the table

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of weird requirement but you can accomplish it as follows. I also don't think you actually want a drill through if you're happy for a Power Query solution and I should have probably done that in the first place. However, as we're still on DAX, the following measure will work in a table or aggregated.

```
Measure = 
VAR o = ALL('Table'[Origin])
VAR d = ALL('Table'[Destination])
VAR i = INTERSECT(o, d)
RETURN 

IF(HASONEVALUE('Table'[Date]), 
    SUMX(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Origin], 'Table'[Destination]),
            "@x", IF('Table'[Destination] IN i || 'Table'[Origin] IN i, 1,0)
        ), [@x]
    ), COUNTROWS(i)
)
```

[image]

You can put a visual level filter on your table to only show rows when the value is 1.